# Some PR to have these guys as contributors?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I'm glad space.SE exists I'm sure it'll be a successful adventure. Before space.SE we have been relying on other websites, some were open, other had a part reserved to subscribers.

In the past, I've been digging in some remarkable sources, that could be very good contributors to this forum if they are interested:

- A French space enthusiast ([Didier Capdevila](https://fr-fr.facebook.com/didier.capdevila)) who runs [CapcomEspace](http://www.capcomespace.net/dossiers/espace_US/shuttle/index.htm) ([Google Translate](https://translate.google.fr/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.capcomespace.net%2Fdossiers%2Fespace_US%2Fshuttle%2Findex.htm&edit-text=)). Unfortunately the site is in French, but I think Didier speaks English. The site is [currently active](https://translate.google.fr/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.capcomespace.net%2Factualites%2Factualite_spatiale.htm&edit-text=).
- A former KSC employee ([Andrew Scheer](https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrewscheer)), who worked at pad-39. He shot the pad providing details that at the time where not available, and posted them on Flickr ([apacheman](https://www.flickr.com/photos/apacheman/)).
- I also tried to identify a person who shot very rare views at pad-39. Her/his nickname was "jbingham", but I cannot get a clue to the real name, and the photos seems to be removed now. For example, images of the water bags (part of the Shuttle SSWS) have been quite rare (though CapcomEspace did manage to get one):

[image]

Is that part of SE process to contact people that can contribute or help in any way?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you've noticed the 'Know someone who can answer?' box at the bottom of questions without answers. There are templates through the links there that work with the 4 most common services. My guess is the best approach is for people who have some personal connection to the person being invited to take this step. Otherwise maybe it would be annoying. Did you take a crack at it?

Some of the people who participate here are in the industry, I'm sure they bring it up to others if they feel they might want to participate too. The moderators also promote the site as much as they can. I imagine you have noticed from the quality of answers that many people on the site know a great deal and take the time to write up great answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand I can inform someone I know, as you suggest. My question was for the second possibility where the persons running the site may have a standard information and would initiate contact. I was wondering if this was actually a practice in use here.

Comment: The site moderators do outreach, on a personal level. As such it is behind the scenes.